# Ranking a relation between two ranks

Tags: python, pandas

After ranking my `df` with `rank()`, I get:

```
team    ranking_goals_scored  ranking_goals_conceded   next_match
Arsenal      1                     4                   Man United
Man City     2                     5                   Chelsea
Liverpool    3                     2                   Man City
Chelsea      4                     3                   Arsenal
Man United   5                     1                   Liverpool
...
```

Now I would like to have a column called 'rank_potential', ranking the comparison between the two ranks, given the next match.

---

In this scenario, Arsenal x Man United should come first in ranking for 'potential', because the team scoring the most (Arsenal) will face the team conceding the most goals (Man United), ending up with something like:

```
team    ranking_goals_scored  ranking_goals_conceded   next_match   rank_potential
Arsenal      1                     4                   Man United   1
Man City     2                     5                   Chelsea      2
Liverpool    3                     2                   Man City     5
Chelsea      4                     3                   Arsenal      3
Man United   5                     1                   Liverpool    4
```

---

How do I achieve that with pandas?

PS: I'm not sure if my desired output ranking is correct, otherwise I would know how to answer my own question. Measuring the difference between the two ranks is part of the answer. Is ranking is not the way to go here, because some differences will be the same, maybe just sorting by difference would suffice.

Comment: Can you show your output for whole data set ?

Comment: it is just a df with 20 teams, with both ranks from 1 to 20.

Comment: the explanation is unclear to me , So I would like to see more information in expected output

Comment: ok, 2 min, please

Comment: Additionally, how do you rank potential? The way I see it, you can just rank them by the differences in scored vs. conceded. If so, how do you rank those with equal differences.

Comment: good question. maybe just sorting them would suffice, when the difference is equal.